# Graph-Based Information Retrieval - Text Representation

Tags: java, python, nlp, information-retrieval

I want to create a simple graph representation of text where vertices correspond to words and the edges of the graph capture various types of relationships between two vertices. I dont mind the programming language being used. I just want learn so that I can use this knowledge to build my own application. Please, any tutorials, examples, links will be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is really subjective.

Anyway, since a few years there is a workshop co-located with ACL entitled

**Graph-based Methods for Natural Language Processing**

Here is a link for the last edition:

https://sites.google.com/site/textgraphs2017/

And here links for the past editions:

https://sites.google.com/site/textgraphs2017/previous-editions